# IntesectionObserver API fails to fire event upon horizontal scrolling on small screen

Tags: lazy-loading, horizontal-scrolling, intersection-observer

When laying elements horizontally (with horizontal scroll bar), and scrolling left/right,
IntersectionObserver API does not always fire event when an observed element enters the viewport.
This happens on mobile devices or when testing on desktop chrome while setting small dimensions of Responsive screen or mobile screens (iPhone 6/7/8 etc.)

Is there a way to overcome this?
Thank you